# Solve $f(5)$ when its given the function

Tags: functions, functional-equations

It is given the function $f(x)-3f(8-x)=x$

How can I find $f(5)$?

Comment: How is it linked with Trigonometry?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Put $x=a,8-a$  and solve the two simultaneous linear equations for $f(a)$

Comment: @benedito, Have you found $f(a)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

With $f(3)=3+3f(5)$ you get 
$$f(5)=5+3f(3)=5+3(3+f(5))=5+9+3f(5)$$
$$2f(5)=-14$$
$$f(5)=-7$$